# Setting Windows XP Embedded locale programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp, locale

Is there a way to set the system locale settings (possibly using shortcodes e.g. en-US) programmatically within Windows XP Embedded from a C# Windows Form Application?

Preferably this would be a combo-box selector which allows the user to select from a list of available regional formats similar/identical to intl.cpl. This needs to run on a non-administrator account which does not have access to intl.cpl (I will administratively elevate the application).

Comment: have you looked at `Culture.Info`

Comment: This only changes the application's culture/locale and not the system locale I thought?

Comment: so are you saying this would not work something like this 
`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");`

Comment: This only changes the thread of the application, not the SYSTEM locale. What I am asking likely requires updates to the registry so that it sets the SYSTEM locale, not the application CultureUI.

Comment: Why do you need to know why I need to do this? A better why question is..."Why down vote a question which is very clear and has been answered within 10 minutes with the required answer just because you do not understand it?"

Comment: @Accolade A very common response (impudence). 1- I posted the link why you shouldn't use this API. 2- I wanted to know why you need this because If I knew your *real* problem, I could post a better answer. I think you wouldn't mind if I vote you down now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an API. Check this one:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetLocaleInfo(uint Locale, uint LCType, string lpLCData);
```

With this function from `kernel32.dll` you'll be able to set the locale of the system.

The first parameter specifies what locale will the function use when interpreting the data of `lpLCData`.

The second parameter specifies the type of locale you're setting (date format, month names, day names, currency format, etc)

The third parameter specifies the format you're going to set. It has to be compatible with the type you specified on the second parameter.

You can check the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info.

Be aware that, as yoy say, this modifies the registry of the whole system, so be very careful and very sure why are you trying to do this.

Comment: I don't think that an application should use this api. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The link I provide to the MSDN page states the same. And actually neither I do think someone should use this API. I just answered the question, but also clarifying it's a very dangerous (and uncommon) thing to do.